# Inline if statement escapes HTML characters

Tags: python, mako

So I'm playing with Mako on Pyramid and I'm trying to do inline if statements.

```
<li>${'<a href="#">Opinions</a></li>' if whichnav == 'opinions' else 'Opinions'}
```

Outputs:

```
<li>&lt;a href=&#34;#&#34;&gt;Opinions&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
```

Whereas:

```
% if whichnav =='opinions':
      <li><a href="#">Opinions</a></li>
% else:
      <li>Opinions</li>
% endif
```

Outputs correctly without escaping the HTML characters:

```
<li><a href="#">Opinions</a></li>
```

I want to make my code as clean as possible so inline if statements are preferable, but I don't understand why HTML characters are escaped whereas using % they are not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your HTML is being escaped.  What happens if you change your inline `if` to this:

```
${'<a href="#">Opinions</a></li>' if whichnav == 'opinions' else 'Opinions' | n}
```

(Edit: Put the `| n` to disable the filtering AFTER the conditional).

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks for pointing out where to [look](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/filtering.html#turning-off-filtering-with-the-n-filter)!.

Comment: Cool! I was gonna link that too, but then I got owned.